# Mobile ads compatible with google play policies

Tags: android, google-play, ads

I am looking for an AdMob alternative that complies with Gogle Play ad policies (using Android Advertising ID instead of the device ID).
I found that mobup is able to do so (https://dev.twitter.com/mopub/android/getting-started).

And what about other ad networks? Which of them are safe to use at GooglePlay?

Comment: Go to Admob.com, look at Mediation and it lists them all there. Seeing that you are starting to implement ads, I would highly suggest you start with Admob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add on to my comment, here is a list of trusted of mobile Ad networks to with Google Play Services:

```
AdColony
AdFalcon
Adfonic
AdMob
AdRally
ADResultSDK
AMoAd
Amobee
AppFlood
Appsfire
BrightRoll
Domob
Drawbridge 
Facebook
Flurry
HUNT Mobile Ads
iAd
InMobi
Leadbolt
LifeStreet Media
LiquidM
LG U+AD
MdotM
Medialets
Millennial Media 
MobFox
Mojiva
MoPub
Nend
Nexage
Pontiflex
Rhythm NewMedia
TapIt
Tencent GDT
Tremor Video
Vpon
Vdopia
Vserv
```

**Source**: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/mediation-networks?hl=en

You can use **Admob** with **Mediation**: https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3063564?hl=en and https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6000997

Here is how to set it up: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/mediation?hl=en